# How to list blog id in blogger

Tags: c#, blogger

I have the following code that will get the title of each blog of a blogger account. This will list the title of blogs, but what I need is to display the id of blogs. Is there a way to do that?

```
FeedQuery query = new FeedQuery();
query.Uri = new Uri("http://www.blogger.com/feeds/default/blogs");
AtomFeed feed = null;
try
{
  feed = service.Query(query);
  foreach (AtomEntry entry in feed.Entries)
  {
    label1.Text += "Blog ID: " +   entry.Title.Text  ;
  }
}

catch {}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: having no experience with this.  it looks like there's an AtomEntry.Id member. is that what you want?

Comment: Yes.. I tried AtomEntry.Id but not working...

Answer (score 0):

I could get the blogid using following code. It's kind of dirty but does the job. Add some null check to avoid exceptions.

```
foreach (AtomEntry entry in feed.Entries)
  {
    string[] url = entry.SelfUri.ToString().Split('/');
    string blogid = url[url.Length - 1];
  }
```